# ternary operator not rendering markup in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render some loading elements (just empty `<li>`'s at this point) within a component while I wait for `axios` to retrieve data from my backend. To do this I'm using a ternary operator, but for some reason I'm not getting any rendering from it - no matter if the condition is evaluates to `true` or `false`.

### My Code

```
class Content extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { currentItemIndex: 0 };
    }

    render(){
        // results will either be an empty array [] or an array populated with objects
        let results = this.props.results;
        return <div className="content">
            // note that this className will return the correct results using the same logic
            <div className={(results.length ? "results" : "loading")}>
                <ul>{ 
                    results.length ? 
                    // results has data so render it all out
                    results.map(data => {
                        const index = this.state.currentItemIndex + 1;
                        this.setState({ currentItemIndex: index });

                        return <Result key={data.slug} data={data} index={index} />
                    }) :
                    // results has no data so render 8 empty list elements
                    new Array(8).map(() => <li></li>)
                }</ul>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

So, using the above code, whether my `results` array is populated or not, it will neither render the `<Result />` component *OR* the 8 empty `<li>`'s like it should. Even stranger, if I change the code to something like this:

```
{ results.length ? "there are results" : "no results" }
```

It will do it just fine.

I'm fairly new to **React** so the problem may seem obvious, but as far as I'm aware, I'm doing everything correctly. All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Try to inspect the elements with DevTool, my guess is its a CSS problem. For further help try making reproducible example in a sandbox. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Not a CSS problem, the elements don't ever appear in the DOM.

Comment: Also, you mutate state `++this.state.currentItemIndex`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: @DennisVash oh, thanks for that pickup, didn't even notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You are calling `this.setState()` in the `render` which will result in a `Maximum update depth exceeded` error. I'm not sure what you are doing with the `currentItemIndex`, but you should move that `this.setState()` call to some handler outside of the `render`.
2. You don't get an array with 8 elements when you do `new Array(8)`. From the [docs on Array() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array):

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values)

In your case, there are no items in the array so the `map` returns no list items.

You can achieve this by doing:

```js
Array.from({ length: 8 }).map((x) => {
  console.log(x);
  //you could return <li></li> in your case
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I ended up just using the `useState` hook to update my index and converted my `class` component to a functional component.